# Flutter to iOS - Use FlutterMethodChannel to iOS files in Objective C

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, appdelegate, flutter-method-channel

I have a working **Flutter** Project.

Then I have to connect to a printer. This printer company provided an API/SDK for me to consume. The code is written in a .h and .a file.

**This is just an iOS connection, no need for Android.**

To test a simple connection, these are what I did:

1. I created a folder inside ios/Runner project and named it "PrinterCheck", this folder contains the .a and .h files they provided.
2. I modified my AppDelegate

```
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController;
    let methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "PrinterCheck", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
    
    methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler{
      (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in
        if("printHello" == call.method){
          //TODO: execute a simple print to make sure it connects to the files
          result(true);
        } else {
          result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
        }
    }

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

3. I created a .m file with a simple printHello method returning a false bool value just to test a connection. I put this .m file in the same folder where the .h and .a are located.

```
- (BOOL)printHello:(NSString *)printValue {
    return false;
}
```

4. And in Dart, I invoke the method

```
const platform = const MethodChannel('PrinterCheck');
var result = await platform.invokeMethod('printHello', {"printValue": "test"});
```

I want to know how I can invoke from the TODO line the printHello from .m file. The result(true) is working as is but I want to print false from .m file instead.  Thank you.